No carga la fuente 20px Emulogic
La fuente que tiene que cargarse es esta
La estoy usando para el texto del "score" y "lives" en mi pagina de game.js, donde se carga este texto, en general todos los textos deberían cargarse con esta fuente
Este es mi código de lives :
let drawLives = () => {
canvasContext.font = "20px Emulogic" 
canvasContext.fillStyle = "white"
canvasContext.fillText(
    "Lives: ", 
    220, 
    oneBlockSize * (map.length + 1) + 10
);
for (let i = 0; i < lives; i++){
    canvasContext.drawImage(
        pacmanFrames,
        2 * oneBlockSize,
        0,
        oneBlockSize,
        oneBlockSize,
        350 + i * oneBlockSize,
        oneBlockSize * map.length + 1,
        oneBlockSize,
        oneBlockSize,
    );
}

}
y este es el de score:
let drawScore = () => {
canvasContext.font = "20px Emulogic";
canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
canvasContext.fillText(
    "Score: " + score, 
    0, 
    oneBlockSize * (map.length + 1) + 10
);

};
estas son las constantes que uso:
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

y este es mi html:

Pero cuando corro el proyecto no me carga el texto con la fuente que deberia, sino esta:


Tal vez encuentres la respuesta aquí ¿Cómo sé qué fuentes tiene un sistema y si debo importarlas o no a la hora de cargar una página?.
